# How do I upload a photo to a friend's wall?

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I am using the Facebook C# SDK (Graph API) and I am able to post photos to the logged-in user's wall ('me'), but when trying to replace the 'me' with one of the logged-in user's friends id, it still posts the photo to the logged-in user's wall instead to the friend's wall, using this code:

```
fb.PostAsync("selecteFriendIDHere/photos", parameters);
```

Comment: please show complete code maybe something wrong in your code which you yet not showed